# PHP can't find cookie file after cURL request

Tags: php, cookies, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to log into a forum using cURL and save the cookie to a file, then parse the cookie to get the `phpbb2mysql_sid` cookie. Here's my code thus far:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

$cookieFile = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\cookies\\' . uniqid(true);

// Login
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/phpbb2/login.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$postVars = array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'testing', 'autologin' => 'on', 'login' => 'Log in');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

// Parse sid from cookie file
preg_match('/phpbb2mysql_sid\t(.*)/', file_get_contents($cookieFile), $match);
$sId = $match[1];

echo $sId;
```

However, I'm getting this error when I run the script:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\cookies\150367764c4ef3) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\leech\post.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php on line 19
```

If I check my filesystem the file is there. And the code to get the file contents is **after** the cURL request, so the file should exist, right?

Comment: Have you tried `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "path\to\cookiejar.txt");` ? Also, what does `echo getcwd();` output?

Comment: `$cookieFile = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\cookies\\' . uniqid(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. The cookie file is only saved once `curl_close()` is called. Simply close the cURL handle before the `file_get_contents()` call and it works like a charm.